# Solaris Update Hosts file Without Rebooting

Tags: solaris, hosts

I'm running Solaris 10 and I'm having issues with a particular network and need to replace host entries in my hosts file. I've updated the hosts file. Is there a refresh the hosts entries without a reboot?

Comment: I don't personally know Solaris, but on every Unix system I've ever used (and even on Windows ones...) changes to the `hosts` file *never* required a reboot to become effective.

Comment: Not to be **that** guy but you could have tested it for yourself in less time than it took to post your question.

Answer (score 4):

No reboot required.
But to be sure the changes take effect you can restart the nscd:

```
pkill nscd
```

SMF should automatically restart the nscd.. or:

```
svcadm restart svc:/system/name-service-cache:default
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Solaris name resolution  behavior is odd in some other ways, see http://blog.superpat.com/2006/06/08/solaris-10-etchosts-gotcha/